# Выбрать строки с датой, у которых разница, не больше определенного значения

Tags: mysql, sql

В селекте я получаю строки из таблицы с временем в формате TIMESTAMP.
Я хочу **посчитать** уникальные строки, **НО с возможной погрешностью в 1 секунду.** В примере ниже, например, 3 уникальные записи (1 и 2 имеют погрешность в 1 секунду, а значит считаются за одну).

Думал сделать для поиска уникальных значений функцию вроде **ABS(time_1 - time_2) > 1.**

1. Можно ли это как-то реализовать на стороне SQL или лучше на стороне сервера, который эти данные будет тянуть?
2. Возможно это сделать без функций? Насколько сильно подобное грузит бд?

Любые подсказки куда лучше рыть приветствуются!

Пример вывода:

```
+------------+
|  time      |
+------------+
| 1583060400 |
+------------+
| 1583060401 |
+------------+
| 1583060460 |
+------------+
| 1583074860 |
+------------+
```

Comment: если значения `1,2,3` то выбрать надо `1,2` или `2,3`, какая из них дублем будет?

Comment: @teran Я немного некорректно составил вопрос, мне нужно просто количество строк, т.е. COUNT(*). Возвращать даты не нужно.

Comment: Если уж вам надо число строк. то данные в приложение точно тащить смысла нет. Какая версия mysql ?

Comment: @teran древняя, 5.7 :(